# CloudKit bytes to array of strings

Tags: cloudkit, ckrecord, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have a record on my CloudKit public database that was made via the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. In Core Data, the attribute is of type `[String]` and when I add it to the public database, it is converted to `Bytes`.

When I fetch this record and try to extract the `[String]` like so

```swift
strings = record["CD_strings"] as! [String]
```

I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '_NSInlineData' (0x7fe5ae87c2a8) to 'NSArray' (0x7fe5ad835f90).

How are you supposed to get the `CKRecordValue` as type `[String]`?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to have the attribute type as `transformable`, add `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` in the transformer field and `[String]` in Custom Class:

[image: Like so...]